# StarTeam SDK: how to list last revisions of files in a given view that have been changed recently

Tags: sdk, starteam

Is anybody able to share some **working** example for doing the following  with StarTeam SDK:

For a given project and view, list all the files that have been changed within N last days, printing the author of the last file revision and their comments for their check-ins?

I would be glad to implement it in any of the following languages: JScript, C#, Java. There are very few examples that come with StarTeam SDK. So I failed to make these examples work in Java (a lot of warning on type mismatch), C# (I didn't found any examples at all) and JScript (currently, I failed to choose the view I need; I can only specify DefaultView).

Thanks,
Racoon